# WoW add-ons ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wine, games

so I recently started playing World of Warcraft again, and am trying to get add-ons to work. What I have done so far is found the add-ons folder for WoW in wine, and extracted the add-on I wanted to use there. the path is 
~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/World of Warcraft/Interface/AddOns
So I extracted the add-on to that file, the files are all there but when I open WoW, I still get no add-ons button. Am I doing something wrong or missing something? TIA

Comment: Sorry, but unless you're sure that in Windows it works just right this way *(since you're asked whether you're doing wrong or not, I guess you're not sure)*, I think, it is rather a game specific question, than of Wine.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I did end up figuring it out!

Comment: You can in this case answer your own question, so that other peoples were aware how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

So, adding add-ons to World of Warcraft works the same on linux as it does as windows. The problem I had, is I installed Diablo 3 first, and by doing that, when I installed WoW, I had to find the WoW file inside the diablo 3 file. then you can navigate through World of Warcraft > interface > addons, and put them there and they work fine!